# Question about countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

let $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ countable sets.Which of the following questions is true:

1. A\B is countable
2. A\B is not countable
3. $A \cap B$ is countable
4. $A+B=\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}$ is countable

My attemp:

2. is false: if I consider $A=\mathbb Z, B=\mathbb N$ then A\B=$\mathbb Z^-$ that is a countable set

A\B and $A \cap B$ are subsets of a countable set so they can be finite or countable so the cases 1) and 3) don't consider the finite case

so is is 4) true?

Comment: Could you define "numerable" here please?

Comment: a set $A$ is numerable if exists a bijective function from $\mathbb N$ to $A$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: What definition of countable are you using.  Some definitions use countable may be finite and some use countable must be infinite.  It seems you are using contable may be fintite but innumerable must be infinite.  Is that correct.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both finite then $A+B$ is finite.  So whether 4) is true or false depends on your definition of countable and numerable.  If countable may include finite but innumerable may not it is false.  But if countable doesn't include finite, or if numerable can include finite it is true.

Comment: My teacher said that a a set is countable if can be take in one to one  correspondance with $\mathbb N$

Comment: "My teacher said that a a set is countable if can be take in one to one correspondance with N" A good teacher for a low level class should be intuitive as well as technical definitions and explain how the technical describe the intuitive.  "can be taken in one to one correspondance **into** N" (injective but not nesc surjective) means it could be countably infinite *or* finite.  But numerable="bijection N to A" means it *must* be infinite but can but "counted" listed one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definitions:

Finite:  A set $A$ is finite if there exists a bijection $A \to \mathbb J_n =\{1,2,3,.....n\}$.  Intuitively that means there is a precise number of elements and we can count them.

Countable: A set $A$ is countable if there exists an injection (not necessarily surjective) from $A \to \mathbb N$.  (Note: this means an finite sets are countable because the bijection $f:A\to \mathbb J_n$ can be extended to the injection $\overline{f}:A\to \mathbb N$ where $\overline{f}(k) = f(k)$)  Intuitively a countable set may be finite or it could be infinite. If it is infinite we can list the elements one after another and .... count them.

Numerable:  A set $A$ is countable if there exists an injection (which must be injective and surjective) from $A\to \mathbb N$.  Intuitively: Numerable means infinite but we can list them one after another.  Countable means we can list them one after another and the may be finite or not.  Finite means we can list them one after another but they end.

So the intuitive answers are:

1. $A\setminus B$ is countable. true.  If you have a countable set and we list them in order and remove some, what's left can still be listed in the original order.
2. $A\setminus B$ in not numerable.  false.  Your counterexample is good.  So would the integers/naturals less the even integers/naturals.  Or you could do completely disjoint sets $\mathbb N\setminus \mathbb Z^{-1}= \mathbb N$. Or $\mathbb Q\setminus \mathbb N$.

Of course it's *possible* they could be not numerable.  $\mathbb N\setminus \{n\in \mathbb N| n > 5\}= \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ which is countable and finite but *not* numerable.

It could even be empty.  Example: $\mathbb N\setminus \mathbb Z = \emptyset$.

3. $A\cup B$ is countable.  True.  And your reason that a subset of a countable set is countable is good.  Note if either $A$ or $B$ is finite then the intesection is finite.  But if both are numerable the intersection could be numerable, finite, or empty.
4. $A+B$ is numerable.  False.  It could be if either $A$ or $B$ is numerable and the other is non-empty.  But if both are finite then $A+B$ is finite.

$A+B$ will always be countable.

Those are all *intuitive* answers but they are correct.  If we were asked to prove them we'd have to show more rigor.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the cardinality of $A + B$ will not exceed the cardinality of $A \times B$. This is because for each sum $a + b$ in $A + B$, there exists a corresponding pair $(a, b)$ in $A \times B$. In other words, there exists a surjective function from $A \times B$ to $A + B$.

Since, $A$ and $B$ are countable sets (if that is what you mean by *numerable*), then $A \times B$ is countable. Therefore, $A + B$ must also be countable.

**Update:** If we define *numerable* as having a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set, then in this case, finite sets can not be numerable. If $A$ and $B$ are finite, then $A + B$ is also finite and hence, can not be numerable.